# Deleting Records in a Nested Table (plsql)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I want to delete the elements that the column (emp_sal) in the record type has 5000+, but it's giving me a error. I don't know if i'm putting the .DELETE method in the correct area.
code:

```
    DECLARE

    TYPE rec IS RECORD (

    emp_id HR.EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
    emp_fname HR.EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%TYPE,
    emp_lname HR.EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME%TYPE,
    emp_job HR.EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID%TYPE,
    emp_sal HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE );

    TYPE rec_table IS TABLE OF rec;
    rec_list rec_table := rec_table();

BEGIN

  SELECT HR.EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID,
         HR.EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME,
         HR.EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME,
         HR.EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID,
         HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY
         BULK COLLECT INTO rec_list
         FROM HR.EMPLOYEES;

  FOR i IN rec_list.FIRST..rec_list.LAST LOOP

     IF (rec_list(i).emp_sal > 5000) THEN

       rec_list(i).DELETE();

     END IF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('element: '||i||' '||
                         'emp id: '||rec_list(i).emp_id||
                         ' full name: '||rec_list(i).emp_fname||
                         ' '||rec_list(i).emp_lname||
                         ' job: '||rec_list(i).emp_job||
                         ' salary: '||rec_list(i).emp_sal);

  END LOOP;

END;
```

Output:

```
ORA-06550: line 28, column 20: PLS-00302: component 'DELETE' must be declared
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to delete an element from a collection you are using it wrong

```
DELETE with no parameters removes all elements from a collection, setting COUNT to 0.
DELETE(n) removes the nth element from an associative array with a numeric key or a nested table. If the associative array has a string key, the element corresponding to the key value is deleted. If n is null, DELETE(n) does nothing.
DELETE(m,n) removes all elements in the range m..n from an associative array or nested table. If m is larger than n or if m or n is NULL, DELETE(m,n) does nothing.
```

so in your example the correct the correct is

```
IF (rec_list(i).emp_sal > 5000) THEN

   rec_list.DELETE(i);

END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED.

Did this:

```
    FOR i IN rec_list.FIRST..rec_list.LAST LOOP

     IF (rec_list(i).emp_sal > 5000) THEN

       rec_list.DELETE(i);

      CONTINUE;

     END IF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('element: '||i||' '||
                         'emp id: '||rec_list(i).emp_id||
                         ' full name: '||rec_list(i).emp_fname||
                         ' '||rec_list(i).emp_lname||
                         ' job: '||rec_list(i).emp_job||
                         ' salary: '||rec_list(i).emp_sal);

  END LOOP;
```

------------------------output:

```
    element: 6 emp id: 105 full name: David Austin job: IT_PROG salary: 4800
element: 7 emp id: 106 full name: Valli Pataballa job: IT_PROG salary: 4800
element: 8 emp id: 107 full name: Diana Lorentz job: IT_PROG salary: 4200
element: 16 emp id: 115 full name: Alexander Khoo job: PU_CLERK salary: 3100
element: 17 emp id: 116 full name: Shelli Baida job: PU_CLERK salary: 2900
element: 18 emp id: 117 full name: Sigal Tobias job: PU_CLERK salary: 2800
element: 19 emp id: 118 full name: Guy Himuro job: PU_CLERK salary: 2600
element: 20 emp id: 119 full name: Karen Colmenares job: PU_CLERK salary: 2500
element: 26 emp id: 125 full name: Julia Nayer job: ST_CLERK salary: 3200
```

Thanks!